# How to run xorg in docker with custom edid?

Tags: docker, virtualization, headless, xorg

Im truing to fully functional X11 server in headless mode in docker container without using xvfb and host X-socket.

But ny  log looks like:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 21240.680] Current Operating System: Linux 5f44429f13e9 6.7.0-arch3-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 13 Jan 2024 14:37:14 +0000 x86_64
[ 21240.680] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=597d2a3d-af3c-43a3-b657-5e6afffc2f2f rw zswap.enabled=0 rootfstype=ext4 loglevel=1 quiet raid=noautodetect nowatchdog split_lock_detect=off amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xff>
[ 21240.680]
[ 21240.680] Current version of pixman: 0.43.0
[ 21240.680]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 21240.680] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 21240.680] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jan 19 14:06:46 2024
[ 21240.680] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 21240.680] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 21240.680] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 21240.680] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[ 21240.680] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 21240.681] (==) No device specified for screen "Screen0".
        Using the first device section listed.
[ 21240.681] (**) |   |-->Device "AMD"
[ 21240.681] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Screen0".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 21240.681] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 21240.681] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 21240.681] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 21240.681] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 21240.681] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 21240.681] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/TTF,
        /usr/share/fonts/OTF,
        /usr/share/fonts/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[ 21240.681] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 21240.681] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 21240.681] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 21240.681]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 21240.681]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[ 21240.681]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[ 21240.681]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 21240.681] (EE) dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
[ 21240.681] (++) using VT number 1

[ 21240.681] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 21240.682] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[ 21240.682] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:29:00.0/0000:2a:00.0/0000:2b:00.0/drm/card1
[ 21240.688] (--) PCI:*(43@0:0:0) 1002:747e:1da2:475a rev 200, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xe0000000/2097152, 0xfc800000/1048576, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 21240.688] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[ 21240.688] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 21240.688] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 21240.689] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 21240.689]    compiled for 1.21.1.11, module version = 1.0.0
[ 21240.689]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 21240.689] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[ 21240.689] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[ 21240.690] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 21240.690]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 23.0.0
[ 21240.690]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 21240.690]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 21240.690] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
        All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[ 21240.690] (EE) AMDGPU(0): [drm] device is not DRM master.
[ 21240.690] (II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[ 21240.691] (EE) AMDGPU(1): [drm] device is not DRM master.
[ 21240.691] (EE) AMDGPU(G0): [drm] device is not DRM master.
[ 21240.691] (EE) AMDGPU(G0): [drm] device is not DRM master.
[ 21240.691] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[ 21240.691] (II) AMDGPU(0): AMDGPUFreeScreen
[ 21240.691] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[ 21240.691] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[ 21240.691] (II) AMDGPU(0): AMDGPUFreeScreen
[ 21240.691] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[ 21240.691] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[ 21240.691] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 21240.691] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[ 21240.691] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[ 21240.691] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 21240.691] (EE)
[ 21240.709] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Here is my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-xorg-virtual-screen.conf :

```
`Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    #Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DP-0"
    Option         "CustomEDID" "DP-0:/root/custom.edid"
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DP-0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection`

Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMD"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Screen 0
EndSection
```

I'm tried to use diferent edid files but nosing.
I'm running docker with : docker run -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri -it --privileged -it arch:xorg
The main goal to get xorgserver in container with support amd GPU, vulkan as a openGL and DRI3.`

Comment: A container is normally isolated from the host's hardware devices.  Do you have a specific reason to want this in a container?  Are you writing any code to support this, or are you just asking about mechanics of configuring Xorg?  Non-programming questions might be more appropriate on another site like [unix.se].